# Outlook Anywhere config on Exchange 2010 server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I'm trying to configure the Outlook Anywhere feature on Exchange 2010 server so any user form outside my domain can be able to access the corporate e-mail account and i get the following error:
"Cannot open your default e-mail folders. You must connect to Microsoft Exchange with the current profile before you can synchronize your folders with your Outlook data file (.ost)"

I'm using Outlook 2010 if that matters, and I'm not sure if the exchange config is ok..

One more thing, I've managed to pass over the SSL Certificate error by issuing one from my own CA and imported it on the test PC (will buy one when I will get everything working on this PC) so the https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com results are kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Seems like you skipped a few steps: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123542(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: already did them steps twice...can't get to the bottom of this..someone even sugested to install RPC over HTTP Proxy feature before enabling Outlook Anywhere..please tell me this is not the answer..doing it as we speak, will come back with the result

Comment: You do understand that installing RPC over HTTP Proxy feature is a prerequisite for Outlook Anywhere right? This is clearly indicated on the article I linked to 3 hours ago.  Be sure to note **To use Outlook Anywhere, you must install an SSL certificate that's trusted by the client.** if its not a valid certificate on the client's end the client will reject it and be unable to access their account.

Comment: I'd take a look at the network and firewall rules to make sure the traffic is getting through okay.  Is this the only piece that is not working?

Comment: well, yes, this is the only thing not working right now. About the certificates, I've managed to issue a new cert from my CA (win2008 server role)..do you think this is a valid cert? (i have it installed on the test pc)..and one more thing, when testing the connectivity with www.testexchangeconnectivity.com, besides the SSL cert errors i get:"xRCA is checking the host Autodiscover.domain.com for an HTTP redirect to the Autodiscover service.ExRCA failed to get an HTTP redirect response for Autodiscover.Additional Details An HTTP 403 forbidden response was received..

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a solution to this issue by enabling the Basic Authentication for the Rpc site from IIS...don't know how I've managed to miss that.
Anyway, this also answers to my other question, if the SSL certificate issued by my own CA is valid, and it looks like it is, don't forget to add the CA in the Trusted Root Certification Authority Store on the client's workstation.
Thank you all and hope this is helpful for other people learning the basics of Exchange 2010.

Comment: add your answer as the accepted answer